# Issue after spring 17 on sandbox (.cs41) - Batch not working and permission set not getting inserted as expected?

Tags: apex, batch, spring17

I wrote a batch which insert the permission set based on criteria.

My code worked perfectly in dev sandbox (.cs17) But after i moved to test sandbox(.cs41) then the issue raised by tester.

where this can be address ? Suggestion please.

Comment: Which issues? Are you sure that move your changes as expected? Did you log as SF case?

Comment: If you really thinkg that the problem's in instance - you should contact salesforce support. But most likely it's the problem with your code - please, post the error message.

Comment: If problem is about test class it is most probably about a data problem. Can you share relevant codes and error message?

Comment: Its not about the test class. I checked completely. Its working well in dev instance. I can't catch any exception in log since it skip many detail. But i see the  op:insert sucesss but not created.